# Cronjob not accepting PHP include

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have a PHP file named cronjob.php that includes another PHP file, that is located in the same directory, like this:

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/my_file.php';
```

In DirectAdmin i have made the following cronjob:

```
cd /home/*username*/domains/*domain*/public_html/wp-content/plugins/MyPlugin/classes/ && /usr/local/bin/php -f cronjob.php
```

When the cronjob needs to run, nothing happens. Not even the e-mail is send. Whenever i make a mistake or a typo in the script, the e-mail does get send ( telling me something is wrong, obiously ).

I've tried the following croncommand as well:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -f /home/*username*/domains/*domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/MyPlugin/classes/cronjob.php *
```

*Note:
When the include goes wrong, the email message i get tells me the class i'm trying to make in cronjob.php can't be found ( because it needs to be included from "my_file.php" ), so the path to "cronjob.php" is correct.*

Comment: Since your Directadmin has a cd var try doing the following
    include_once getcwd().'/my_file.php';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
$dir = __DIR__;
include_once $dir . '/my_file.php';
```